# AJAX file upload without JSON

Tags: xml, ajax, json, file, upload

I have PHP installed withou JSON. And not possible to install.
After some googling found only plugin that do upload file by AJAX but all with JSON.
is it possible to remake to xml?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate JSON like:

```
echo "{";
echo                "error: '" . $error . "',\n";
echo                "msg: '" . $msg . "'\n";
echo "}";
```

It doesn't require install any json library in php.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of libraries for decoding/encoding JSON in PHP without needing the compiled extension. Take a look at the list under "PHP" [at JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: I understand JSON. The problem is - I have not JSON extension for PHP installed. So if I see in AJAX datatype: json - I cannot use. I have  PHP Version 5.1.6. I have seen json.org - all libraries require install them - it is a problem.

Comment: You don't need to "install" most libraries. You just download them, put them in a directory accessible to your PHP script and `require` them. You don't need the JSON extension to use them.